# Primary Decomposition Theorem query

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a proof of the Primary Decomposition Theorem, and I am stuck on a part of the proof. The questions are at the end; many thanks for your help.

Let $T:V→V$ be linear operator whose minimal polynomial factors into monic, irreducible, pairwise coprime polynomials: $m_T (t)=p_1 (t)\cdots p_k (t)$. Then:

1. $V$ decomposes as a direct sum of $W_i$, $V=W_i \oplus \cdots \oplus W_k$
2. The $W_i$ are $T$-invariant
3. $p_i$ is the minimal polynomial of $W_i$

Proof of 2
Using the theorem that if $T,S$ are linear maps s.t. $TS=ST$ then Ker$(S)$ is $T$-invariant, if we take $S=p_i(T)$, since $Tp_i(T)=p_i(T)T$, Ker$(p_i(T))$ is $T$-invariant.

We then take Ker$(p_i(T))=W_i$ and $W_i$ is $T$-invariant.

Questions about the proof
1. Why does $Tp_i(T)=p_i(T)T$?
2. Why can we take Ker$(p_i(T))=W_i$? If $V$ decomposes as $W_i$'s is it appropriate for $V$ to only decompose as kernels?

Answer (score 1):

- In fact, it is true that for any polynomial $p$, $T$ and $p(T)$ commute. If $p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_nx^n$, then
  \begin{align}
  Tp(T) &= T(a_0I + a_1T + \cdots + a_nT^n) \\
  &= a_0 T + a_1T^2 + \cdots + a_n T^{n+1} \\
  &= (a_0I + a_1T + \cdots + a_nT^n)T = p(T)T.
  \end{align}
- I don't understand the second question. Is the part $1$ supposed to have been proved already?

Comment: Thanks for this! Here is the proof I am working from. I don't think I've missed anything in the explanation above https://everything2.com/title/Primary+decomposition+theorem